# Theorems of the circumference (geometry)

Tags: geometry, alternative-proof

I was studying the circumference and theorems of that in my book. There are two theorems that I wanted to demonstrate, but, when I did it, it somehow disappointed me and I´d like to know how you´d prove it, if you need me to give my demonstration it´s ok, but I don´t, I think It could demonstrated in other ways but don´t know how. I´ll show them in pictures.

[image]

[image]

I´d also like to know how to prove the theorem that says, that if I have a tangent line, that touches the circumference in $P$, is perpendicular to radius drawn from the centre that point $P$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if you don't show your proofs, it may still help to give some hints of your level in geometry, and what kind of answers you are looking for.

Comment: Any kind of answers, well, I am in 9th grade, but the way I proved it was somewhat disappointing, so I wanted to see how other people would do it.

Answer (score 2):

See the attached figure.

The first result can be proved from the second result. In particular, if $\angle BAC =180^o$ then $\angle BDC =90^o$. The proof of the second result is very simple.

In the figure, $\triangle ABD$ is isosceles. Therefore, $$\angle ABD = \angle ADB = \alpha.$$Also, $\triangle ACD$ is isosceles. Consequently, $$\angle ACD = \angle ADC = \beta.$$
Further, $$\angle BAD = 180^\circ - 2\alpha,$$and $$\angle BAE = 180^\circ - \angle BAD = 2\alpha.$$
Likewise, $$\angle EAC = 2 \beta.$$
Therefore, $$\angle BAC = 2 \alpha + 2\beta = 2(\alpha + \beta)=2\angle BDC.$$

Regarding the tangent line result, I give you a hint. A line segment drawn from a point (center of the circle in your case) to a line (the tangent line in your case) has the shortest length when the segment is perpendicular to the line.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Math Lover, it´s true what you say, i hadn´t looked at it that way, =)

Comment: I didn´t understand what you meant =(.

Comment: @joseestebanbeleñobarrozo What specifically you couldn't understand?

Comment: `first result can be proved from the second` Indeed, +1 for that. `regarding the tangent line result` On the same theme, this can be proved from the *first* result. Consider (on OP's *first* figure) the case where point $D$ approaches $B$. At the limit, the line $DB$ approaches the tangent at $B\,$, and $\angle CBD \to 90^\circ$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for upvoting my answer. Yes, I think that the first result can be used to prove the tangent result as you mentioned.

Comment: @dxiv I didn´t understand how to prove the tangent line result =(.

Comment: @joseestebanbeleñobarrozo On the first figure, once you proved that $BD \perp CD\,$, it follows that $\angle CBD = 180^\circ - \angle BCD - \angle BDC = 90^\circ - \angle BCD\,$. When $D \to B$ the angle $\angle BCD \to 0^\circ\,$, so $\angle CBD \to 90^\circ\,$. That's the case where, in the limit, the secant line $BD$ has a single point in common with the circle at $B \equiv D\,$, so by definition of the tangent it is the tangent at $D\,$, and the angle between the tangent and the radius $AB$ is therefore $90^\circ\,$.

Comment: Well, I might have misunderstood something. What I wanted to prove was the angle between the tangent and the radius (that touches the point $P$ where the tangent passes) makes an angle of $90°$.

Answer (score 0):

For a direct proof of the first problem (without using the second result), let $E$ be the other intersection of $DA$ with the circle. Then $\,BECD\,$ is a parallelogram since the diagonals bisect $\,AD=AE=R$, $AB=AC=R\,$ where $\,R\,$ is the radius of the circle, and is in fact a rectangle since $\,BC=DE=2R\,$ and a parallelogram whose diagonals are equal is a rectangle.

(*To prove that a parallelogram with equal diagonals is a rectangle, if not obvious, show for example that $\,\triangle DBE \equiv \triangle BDC\,$ as having all sides pairwise equal, which implies $\,\angle DBE = \angle BDC\,$, but on the other hand $\,\angle DBE + \angle BDC = 180^\circ\,$ as consecutive interior angles in a parallelogram*.)

Comment: Yes, that´s a good way to prove it, thanks.

Comment: Can I also ask, How do you do those drawings with?

Comment: Not *my* drawings, but see [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) for example.