# Proving that a tangent line to a circle meets the radius to the point of tangency at a right angle

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

Let's suppose I have a circumference, its centre $O$ and a point $P$ that lies on the circumference. Now, if I draw the tangent line that passes through point $P$, and draw the radius $OP$, it forms an angle of $90^\circ$ degrees.

[image]

In other words, we have to prove that $\angle OPA = 90°$ if $\overleftrightarrow {PA}$ touches that circumference in just one a point (point $P$).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This follows directly from either of the two other questions you asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388611/theorems-of-the-circumference-geometry) a few days ago. In the first figure, let $D \to B$ (also see [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388611/theorems-of-the-circumference-geometry#comment4936536_2388615) there). In the second figure, take $DE$ to be a diameter through $A$ then let $F \to D\,$, then at the limit the angle $\angle EDF$ is half the arc subtended by the diameter $DE$ i.e. $90^\circ\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the point on the line of tangency from $A$ to the circle which minimizes the distance to the center $O$. Let $T$ be the foot of the perpendicular from the center $O$ to this tangency line $PA$. We wish to show that $P$ and $T$ are the same point. To do this, focus on the triangle $OTP$, which is formed assuming that $P$ and $T$ are different points.

Note that $\angle OTP = 90^\circ$, and $OP < OT$. Therefore, it follows that $\angle OPT > \angle OTP > 90^\circ$, because a larger side is always opposite a larger angle in a triangle. However, this contradicts the fact that the sum of the angles of the triangle $OTP$ equal $180^\circ$.

Hence, the contradiction is complete and $T = P$. In particular, the tangent is intersected perpendicularly by the diameter which passes through the point of intersection with the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the shortest distance between a point $A$ and a line $l$ is the line segment joining the point $A$ to some point $B$ on $l$ such that $AB \perp l$.

Assume that there exists some point $P'$ on $l$ such that $OP' \lt OP$. Then, since $l$ intersects the circle only at $P$ and does not pass through it, $OP=r$ where $r$ is the radius of the circle, and since $P'$ is not in the circle, $OP' \gt r$. Thus $OP\lt OP'$ and we have a contradiction, telling us that there is no such point $P'$, and $OP$ is the shortest distance from $O$ to $l$, meaning that it is $\perp$ to $l$.

Answer (score 0):

Create another point $B$ to the left of point $P$ on the line $AP.$ Rotate the line $AP$ clockwise around the circle until it is parallel to its original position. Fold the circle along a line parallel to $AP$ through its center. Note that $\angle OPA$ perfectly overlaps $\angle OPB.$ That is, $2\angle OPA = 180.$